# Exclude test directories in multi-module maven projecty from JaCoCo when using Azure build pipeline

Tags: java, azure, maven

This feels like it should be easy, so please help point me in the correct direction.

I am successfully using maven to build my java project using a Azure Pipeline. I am also successfully getting JaCoCo coverage reports.

I have a maven project with multiple modules. Below is a sample project structure. I want to exclude everything in all the sub src/test/java directories/packages.

myproject

```
mod1
    src/main/java/...
    src/test/java/...
    pom.xml
mod2
    src/main/java/...
    src/test/java/...
    pom.xml
pom.xml
```

I would have expected something like setting `codeCoverageClassFilter` to `-:*.src.test.java*.*`, but none of my variations have worked. What is the correct statement to exclude all these test directories?

Answer (score 1):

For excluded test add next configuration in pom parent

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>com/acme/test/*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <!-- prepare agent for measuring integration tests -->
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-site</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: That works for running maven directly, but Azure DevOps seems to ignore that setting. I even tried putting it in pluginManagement, but that also did not seem to work.